# How to get my api data into select list in quasar vue js?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I am getting `object Object` in the select dropdown list

Here is my code

```
<q-select v-model="product_category" :options="options" label="Project Category" />
```

Script code

```
data () {
return {
  options: [],
 }
},
created () {
this.$axios.get([
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/lailen-inventory/categories'
])
  .then(res => {
    this.options = res.data.categories
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to add `option-label` and `option-value` props on the `<q-select>` tag. If your `res.data.categories` (for example) looks like this

```
[
  { id: 1, name: 'water' },
  { id: 2, name: 'earth' },
  { id: 3, name: 'fire' },
  { id: 4, name: 'air' }
]
```

then your `<q-select>` tag should look like this

```
<q-select
  v-model="product_category"
  :options="options"
  option-value="id"
  option-label="name"
  label="Project Category"
/>
```

Comment: this solved my issue ty

Comment: sure, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You could make your value an object containing the type and id. Like this:

```
data () {
    selectOptions: [{
        label: yourInitialObject.title,
        value: {
           id: yourInitialObject.id,
           type: yourInitialObject.type
        }
    }]
}
```